# ERROR 1290 MYSQL secure-file-priv option

Tags: mysql

I have a database which I have been LOADING text files, these were stored in `/tmp`.

for reasons of permits however this morning when I turn the computer the files were no longer in that folder and attempt the LOAD gives me the next

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it can not execute esta statement

I had any problems to use the LOAD so far what could be?

Comment: That option contains a directory name. When it's set, you can only load files from that directory. So if you have `--secure-file-priv=/tmp`, you can only load from `/tmp`.

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Comment: I already configure my.cnf file and put                                                    [mysqld]: secure_file_priv=NULL and it didnt work yet

Comment: What version of MySQL? `NULL` became valid in 5.7.6, and it means that you can't use `LOAD DATA INFILE` at all.

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation, it explains it in great detail. You should be able to figure out the value you want from that.

Comment: but why it change suddenly? its there any reason?

Comment: How should I know what changed on your server?

Answer (score 0):

- `/tmp` is, by design, cleared on reboot.  This cleans up certain trash that might be left behind by a crash.  And it is a security feature.
- `LOAD FILE INFILE` is a security hole waiting for hackers to march in.  5.7 (finally) got serious about it, and partially plugged it by having `--secure-file-priv`.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on what the security issues are with `LOAD DATA INFILE`? I've been searching around and all I have found are instructions for how to disable it but no information as to _why_ it was implemented in the first place.